# anchor links non-english chrome turns unicode

Tags: html, anchor

I have some Hebrew inner anchor link in my site myurl.com/page#הזמנה
when using Firefox the link translated ok in the URL bar but chrome changes the Hebrew letters to Unicode:
myurl.com/page#%D7%94%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%94.

Did chrome changed the way they behave with non-English inner anchor?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and you mean non-Latin. (That is to say, Arabic, Chinese, Hebrew, Korean, and Russian anchors appear percent-encoded; whereas English, Spanish, French, and Turkish anchors appear properly.)

Chrome 63 does it the ugly (percent-encoded) way, and Firefox 57 does it the nice (Unicode) way. (When you said that Chrome changed the Hebrew letters to Unicode, I am sure that you meant to say that Chrome changed the Hebrew letters to percent-encoding).